# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Endpoint Routing doesn't work for default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I have migrated an existing API project from `2.2` to `3.0` based on guidelines from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Thus I've removed:

```
app.UseMvc(options =>
{
    options.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

and inserted:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Default", pattern: "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

But no controller and action would be bound. All I get for any API I call is 404.

How should I debug it and what do I miss here?

**Update:** The `Startup.cs` file is located in another assembly. We reuse a centralized `Startup.cs` file across many projects.

Comment: No they don't have any attribute. We only have one global default routing rule. Nowhere else we have created any other route, neither in action level, nor the controller level.

Comment: Probably way too late, but since there is no accepted answer: Do you have somewhere in the configuration the option `options.EnableEndpointRouting = false`? Because that tells the framework to continue using the 'old' routing, instead of endpoint routing.

Answer (score 11):

From [Attribute routing vs conventional routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing):

> It's typical to use conventional routes for controllers serving HTML pages for browsers, and attribute routing for controllers serving REST APIs.

From [Build web APIs with ASP.NET Core: Attribute routing requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attribute-routing-requirement):

The `[ApiController]` attribute makes attribute routing a requirement. For example:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Actions are inaccessible via conventional routes defined by `UseEndpoints`, `UseMvc`, or `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute` in Startup.Configure.

If you want to use conventional routes for web api , you need to disable attribute route on web api.

StartUp:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Default",
                pattern: "{controller=default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Web api controller:

```
 //[Route("api/[controller]")]
//[ApiController]
public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
{
    public  ActionResult<string> Index()
    {
        return "value";
    }

    //[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<int> GetById(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

This could be requested by `http://localhost:44888/default/getbyid/123`

Comment: We don't have any attribute other than `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` on our actions. And not attribute at all on our controllers.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgelimo ，please show your `Startup.cs` .

Comment: I had to change back to `UseMvc` with old patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend my solution.

Create your CUSTOM base controller like that.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{id?}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomBaseController : ControllerBase
    {
    }
```

And use CustomBaseController

```
 public class TestController : CustomBaseController
    {
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok($"Test {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        }
    }
```

Rout` **api/Test/test**

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to not support conventional routing even in middleware like **UseEndpoints and UseMvc**
You can find that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attribute-routing-requirement-2)